# Does it make sense to say "перемогти вибори"?

Tags: дієслова, non-native-speaker

One more question based on a Duolingo sentence that looked wrong to me.  How would you normally say "he won the election"?  Which of those are correct?

1. Він переміг вибори (this is what Duolingo says)
2. Він виграв вибори
3. Він переміг у/на виборах
4. any other options I'm missing?

My Polish-based intuition says that 2 and 3 are fine but 1 isn't, but I'm not at all sure. So, is 1 an okay sentence, or if not, why not? Do виграти and перемогти work differently, and if so, why/how?

Comment: Yes, the first is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, in this case I canʼt help with Polish examples. But English can help us with words such as [***win*** and ***beat***](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/english-usage/what-is-the-difference-between-win-defeat-and-beat) for correspondingly *виграти* and *перемогти*.

> <sub>Collins</sub>
>
> 1. **win**
>
>    If you win a war, fight, game, or contest, you defeat your opponent. *We won the game easily. The party had won a great victory.*
> 2. **defeat** and **beat**
>
>    Donʼt say that someone *wins* an enemy or opponent. In a war or battle, you say that one side defeats the other. *The French defeated the English troops.*
>
>    In a game or contest, you say that one person or side defeats or beats the other.
>    *He defeated his rival in the semi-finals and went on to win the tournament.
>    She beat him at chess.*

---

> <sub>Questioneress</sub>
>
> Do виграти and перемогти work differently, and if so, why/how?

Thatʼs why we can say only *виграти приз* not *перемогти приз* as *win a prize*. Therefore the most correct way is *виграти вибори* and *перемогти в/на виборах*. So, your intuition was right.

But it looks like some semantic shift happens. If we speak about very abstract terms such as [*вибори*](//google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B3+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%22&lr=-lang_ru), [*турнір*](//google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B3+%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%80%22&lr=-lang_ru) etc then we can use *перемогти* too like *перемогти вибори*. This phenomenon affecteds words such as [*виграш*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88) and [*програш*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88) which could be used as correspondingly *перемога* and *поразка* too. But be careful here, because something with an abstract or a figurative meaning are usually like a constant expression, therefore it isnʼt am easy theme for non-natives. For example, a non-native from this context may take *матч* as abstract but thereʼre no such *перемогти матч*. Therefore better use the mentioned correct way.

> <sub>Questioneress</sub>
>
> any other options I'm missing?

In this case, no, you didnʼt miss. But I can note that such expression as *здобути перемогу* exists.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding some statistics to the other answers:

- *перемагати/перемогти вибори* — [11 cases in GRAC-16](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&default_attr=word&cql=%5Blemma%3D%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%7C%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B8%22%5D%20%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%22&showresults=1), i.e. **0.2%**;
- *вигравати/виграти вибори* — [2871 cases in GRAC-16](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&default_attr=word&cql=%5Blemma%3D%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%7C%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22%5D%20%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%22&showresults=1), i.e. **46%**;
- *перемагати/перемогти на/у виборах* — [3388 cases in GRAC-16](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&default_attr=word&cql=%5Blemma%3D%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%7C%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B8%22%5D%20%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%7C%D1%83%7C%D0%B2%22%20%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%22&showresults=1), i.e. **54%**.

Comment: That's a great resource for answering this sort of question, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

> My Polish-based intuition says that 2 and 3 are fine but 1 isn't, but I'm not at all sure.

Саме так.

1. Він переміг вибори (this is what Duolingo says) - ❌ПОМИЛКОВО
2. Він виграв вибори - ✅ПРАВИЛЬНО
3. Він переміг у/на виборах - ✅ПРАВИЛЬНО

Comment: Згоден, але варто було б спробувати обґрунтувати відповідь.